# Sending emails to contacts - How to default to general FROM email not user FROM email?

Tags: wordpress, civimail, contacts, email

When I am viewing a contact and I click on their email address to send them an email, FROM email defaults to my logged in user email address. I setup a general email address, which I can change to using the dropdown of FROM addresses. But I would like the default FROM email to be the general email addess and not the logged in user email address.

The help menu says:
*From Address
By default, CiviCRM uses the primary email address of the logged in user as the FROM address when sending emails to contacts. However, users with Administer CiviCRM permission can configure one or more general email addresses that can be selected as an alternative. EXAMPLE: "Client Services" clientservices@example.org
Go to Administer CiviCRM » Communications » FROM Email Addresses to add or edit general email addresses. Make sure these email addresses are valid email accounts with your email service provider.*

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Depending on how many system users you have, you could disable the logged in user to email, add them all as 'from' addresses and then set the default to the generic one.

Comment: The downside to this method, is that everybody's email address is available to everybody else for sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a setting ‘Allow mail from logged in contact’. If this setting is disabled then only the system configured from email addresses will be available for selection.

Administer > System Settings > Outbound Email (SMTP/Sendmail)

Comment: So more of a feature request, but would be nice if you could leave "Allow mail from logged in contact" checked, but then re-order the choices so the default FROM address was the first choice, and their logged in user email was the second choice.